# Set a filter to not activate on a Rest Controller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, controller, jwt, token

I have implemented security(jwt, I was created 2 filters that set in the filter chain and use them for create a jwt token and control, if a user detains the token) on a spring boot project, since it is a test project that has not so much endpoints in every controller, override the ShouldNotFilter method of one filter(the one who controls, if the user has the token) because I don't want this one to be active on some request (like registration/login).
this is the code:

```
  @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
       if(request.getRequestURI().startsWith("/login")
               || request.getRequestURI().startsWith("/api/users/registration"))
           return true;
       return false;
    }
```

but these are the only 2 endpoints, if I have to disable this filter on an entire controller, there is an annotation that i can use to achieve this, or I have to delete this override and use .antMacchers(*list of endpoints*).permitAll()?

EDIT: below you can see the code from my SecurityConfig and the controller with the endpoint ( right now is only this one, but i will add many other endpoints)

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class AuthController {
    private final UserFacadeService userFacadeService;

    @Autowired
    public AuthController(UserFacadeService userFacadeService) {
        this.userFacadeService = userFacadeService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/registration")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> signUp(@RequestBody @Valid UserDTO userDTO){
        return ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
                .body(LocalDateTime.now()
                        + " user created: "
                        + this.userFacadeService.saveUser(userDTO));
    }


}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    private  LoginFilter loginFilter;

    private final JwtFilter jwtFilter;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final ExceptionHandlerFilter exFilter;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(UserService userService,
                          JwtFilter jwtFilter,
                          PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
                          ExceptionHandlerFilter exFilter) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.jwtFilter = jwtFilter;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.exFilter = exFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider dao = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        dao.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        dao.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return new ProviderManager(dao);
    }

    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests((auth)->auth
                        .expressionHandler(webExpressionHandler())
                        .antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST)
                        .permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/api/users/registration")
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
                        .and()
                        .addFilterBefore(exFilter, ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
                        .addFilterAt(loginFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                        .addFilterAt(jwtFilter,BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                );

        return http.build();
    }

    //for implement the hierarchy we need to define
    // a SecurityExpressionHandler and insert it in the filterChain
    private SecurityExpressionHandler<FilterInvocation> webExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler
                = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
        defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy());
        return defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler;
    }

    //define a hierarchy that allow to a User with one role to use
    // every API that his role and the sub Roles are allowed to use
    @Bean
    public RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy() {
        RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
        roleHierarchy.setHierarchy("OPERATOR > CUSTOMER");
        return roleHierarchy;
    }


}
```

Comment: So you only need to change `request.getRequestURI().startsWith("/api/users/registration")` to `request.getRequestURI().startsWith("/api/users/")` then all controller methods are included.

Comment: ok, but if i have a controller with many endpoints, half that must activate the filter and the other half that must not, i have to write every single path or there is some kind of annotation?

Comment: Yes, you have to do it. It is your own custom filter, so you have to implement it by yourself.